# Convert normal time to military and military to normal time

Tags: php, time, php-5.5

So I have a tex field 00:00 and a select for meridian time AM/PM, and i need a way if the user enters the time in normal format 01:25 PM to convert that, I found that, but the problem is if the user enters "13:25" PM I also want it to work.

Any solution? this one only works one way...

```
echo date("H:i", strtotime("01:25 PM"));
```

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you want, the title (2-way conversion and what is military time?) does not seem to match the body. But if you want to use PHP's date and time functions, you need valid input. If you do not have that, you would have to parse the input manually.

Comment: best answer is to constrain the user input in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why shouldn't it work :)

Just use a lowercase "h" (12h format) and a "a" (am/pm) to display the time

```
echo date("h:i a", strtotime("13:25"));
```

Output:

> 01:25 pm

You can find more details about the date function here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php